# How to change flipbox popup display order of jquery-mobile-datebox mm-dd-yyyy display format to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am trying to modify the display order of flipbox of jquery-mobile-datebox but I couldn't find any option for the same. I am trying to do this through jquery but still I think there might be an option for it in flipbox.

Below are images for reference.

Below image shows popup by default

[image]

I require popup showing date | month | year as shown in red border

[image]

I hope someone helps me in this!

Answer (score 4):

I think Killrawr way is the good way but I saw in my case the right "override" field name :
was "overrideDateFieldOrder" instead of "fieldsOrderOverride". I use the last version of datebox.

If you look at the several key/fields in the "i18n" you can see a key named "dateFieldOrder" so 
because i already used some override method by prefix the key by override it's seems running well.

So in my case when i did :

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options, {
                'overrideDateFieldOrder': ['d','m','y']
            });
```

It's running well.

An other way is also to do :

```
$('#mydate').data("options", {"overrideDateFieldOrder": ["d", "m", "y"]});
```

Or the best in your case, i think :

```
    <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"overrideDateFieldOrder":["d", "m", "y"]}' />
```

Notice : usage of " and ' in this last line is important. The tag

`data-option='{"overrideDateFieldOrder":["d", "m", "y"]}'`

run well but not something like

`data-option="{'overrideDateFieldOrder':['d','m','y']}"`

not runs.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you! You're right, Killrawr had the right idea, but it was using the wrong property name. The correct property name is 'overrideDateFieldOrder'.  -  bau - I think you have a mistake in your first paragraph. You wrote '"fieldsOrderOverride" instead of "fieldsOrderOverride"'.  But I think you meant to write '"overrideDateFieldOrder" instead of "fieldsOrderOverride"' ;)

Comment: This is the best answer here.  The option is documented here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/api/dateFieldOrder/  and the use of the "override" prefix is explained a bit better here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/doc/3-2-locale/

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are using this [DatePicker](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/). In which case have you had a look at the all [options](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/demos/api/matrix.html#matrix&ui-page=0-3) i.e. `['m','d','y']`

```
fieldsOrderOverride

Type:
    Array

Default:
    Inherited

Modes:
        time/date/flip/slide

Override the i8n fields order. Option is an array of three items, for 24 clock mode 'a' is ignored. i.e. ['m','d','y']

Valid options:

    y : Year
    m : Month
    d : Day of Month (date)
    h : Hour
    i : Minute
    a : Meridiem
```

Implementation (Sourced [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/demos/mode/timebox.html))

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "fieldsOrderOverride": "d m y" }'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes its the same and I used option mentioned by you but still its displaying popup as month | date | year. Below is the code i have used `<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"  data-options='{"mode": "flipbox","fieldsOrderOverride": "d m y", "minYear": 1912, "maxYear": 2013}'>`

Comment: Saw [these list of options in Text Internationaliztion](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox1/demos/api/matrix.html#matrix&ui-page=0-0)  and updated code as below `<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"  data-options='{"mode": "flipbox","dateFieldOrder": ["d","m","y"], "minYear": 1912, "maxYear": 2013}'>` but still it displays default pop up containing m d y format

Comment: I'll have a look at it tonight sometime or tomorrow, and try and find you a hard-coded solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options="{\"mode\":\"calbox\",\"fieldsOrderOverride\": [\"d\",\"m\",\"y\"],\"headerFormat\":\"%A,%d, %-m, %Y\",\"dateFormat\":\"dd/mm/YYYY\",\"useTodayButton\":true}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Jquery mobile` `datebox` my answer will be useful.

My Html given below

```
<input type="text" name="scheduled_date" id="date-value" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"datebox","afterToday":"true","overrideDateFormat":"%d-%m-%Y","useFocus":true,"overrideDateFieldOrder": "dmy"}' placeholder="Date here">
```

overrideDateFieldOrder": "dmy" is the attribute i used to fix the same issue.

following link will be useful

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/api/dateFieldOrder/